# Using javascript component in iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I want ton use a javascript component in iphone. I don't know how to use javascript in UIWebView.

I want a flip component like a flipping clock in HTC using javascript.
Please help me. I would be grateful to you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.
A good approach is to use a framework like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/). This should save you from writing most native-js interaction.

If you want to perform some proprietary work yourself, you should check [UIWebView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

1. To call a js function from native code:
   stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString
2. To call native from within
   js: change the window.location to a custom url scheme like
   "myscheme://blahblah" and implement a [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate) with a
   shouldStartLoadWithRequest method, which detects the custom scheme
   and routes the url to some native method.

Comment: Thanks sagimann  
But i want single component of a javascript in a web view